# How to serve files/PDF files the reactive way in spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive, spring-webflux

I have the following endpoint code to serve PDF files.

```
@RequestMapping
ResponseEntity<byte[]> getPDF() {
  File file = ...;
  byte[] contents = null;
  try {
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {
      contents = new byte[(int) file.length()];
      fis.read(contents);
    }
  } catch(Exception e) {
    // error handling
  }
  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.setContentDispositionFormData(file.getName(), file.getName());
  headeres.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
  return new ResponseEntity<>(contents, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

How can I convert above  into a reactive type `Flux/Mono` and `DataBuffer`.

I have check `DataBufferUtils` but It doesn't seem to offer what I needed. I didn't find any example either.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve that would be with a `Resource`.

```
@GetMapping(path = "/pdf", produces = "application/pdf")
ResponseEntity<Resource> getPDF() {
  Resource pdfFile = ...;
  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.setContentDispositionFormData(file.getName(), file.getName());
  return ResponseEntity
    .ok().cacheControl(CacheControl.noCache())
    .headers(headers).body(resource);
}
```

Note that `DataBufferUtils` has some useful methods there that convert an `InputStream` to a `Flux<DataBuffer>`, like `DataBufferUtils#read()`. But dealing with a `Resource` is still superior.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how `Resource` works behind the scene? Does it also have back pressure handling like `Flux/Mono` reactive types?

Comment: Yes it does; WebFlux has a `ResourceEncoder` just for that.

Answer (score 2):

Below is the code to return the attachment as byte stream:

```
@GetMapping(
        path = "api/v1/attachment",
        produces = APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE
)
public Mono<byte[]> getAttachment(String url) {
    return rest.get()
            .uri(url)
            .exchange()
            .flatMap(response -> response.toEntity(byte[].class));
}
```

This approach is very simple but the disadvantage is it will the load the entire attachment into memory. If the file size is larger, then it will be a problem.

To overcome we can use `DataBuffer` which will send the data in chunks. This is an efficient solution and it will work for any large size file. Below is the modified code using DataBuffer:

```
@GetMapping(
        path = "api/v1/attachment",
        produces = APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE
)
public Flux<DataBuffer> getAttachment(String url) {
    return rest.get()
            .uri(url)
            .exchange()
            .flatMapMany(response -> response.toEntity(DataBuffer.class));
}
```

In this way, we can send attachments in a reactive fashion.

Comment: f I'm correct, the whole body is loaded into memory what can be an issue on for really big files

Comment: @KrzysztofSkrzynecki Yes.. The optimized way to send the data is chunks to the client..

Comment: I get reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed BEFORE response when using the second approach

Comment: @KrzysztofSkrzynecki Entire image won't be loaded into the memory. Using reactive, we are loading only one chunk at a time and returning back to the client.

Comment: @abitcode Please try to increase the timeout for webclient builder..

Comment: @SudharsanThumatti long time since I have tested it (May 2020) but after another review I'm pretty sure that because `response.toEntity(DataBuffer.class)` creates Mono object, whole response needs to be loaded into memory before it is sent further. `.bodyToFlux( DataBuffer.class )` does splitting into chunk for you

Answer (score 0):

**Same Problem with me.**

I use `Webflux Spring WebClient`

I write style `RouterFunction`

My solution below,

**ETaxServiceClient.java**

```
final WebClient defaultWebClient;


public Mono<byte[]> eTaxPdf(String id) {
    return defaultWebClient
            .get()
            .uri("-- URL PDF File --")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            .exchange()
            .log("eTaxPdf -> call other service")
            .flatMap(response -> response.toEntity(byte[].class))
            .flatMap(responseEntity -> Mono.just(Objects.requireNonNull(responseEntity.getBody())));
}
```

**ETaxHandle.java**

```
@NotNull
public Mono<ServerResponse> eTaxPdf(ServerRequest sr) {
    Consumer<HttpHeaders> headers = httpHeaders -> {
        httpHeaders.setCacheControl(CacheControl.noCache());
        httpHeaders.setContentDisposition(
                ContentDisposition.builder("inline")
                        .filename(sr.pathVariable("id") + ".pdf")
                        .build()
        );
    };
    return successPDF(eTaxServiceClient
            .eTaxPdf(sr.pathVariable("id"))
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.empty()), headers);
}
```

**ETaxRouter.java**

```
@Bean
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routerFunctionV1(ETaxHandle handler) {
    return route()
            .path("/api/v1/e-tax-invoices", builder -> builder
                    .GET("/{id}", handler::eTaxPdf)
            )
            .build();
}
```

**CommonHandler.java**

```
Mono<ServerResponse> successPDF(Mono<?> mono, Consumer<HttpHeaders> headers) {
    return ServerResponse.ok()
            .headers(headers)
            .contentType(APPLICATION_PDF)
            .body(mono.map(m -> m)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic()), byte[].class);
}
```

**Result: Successfully displayed on the browser.**

Work for me.

[image]

Comment: If I'm correct, the whole body is loaded into memory what can be an issue on for really big files